# Uploading file using AJAX and PHP gives unknown error (BIF jQuery plugin)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Few things are harder to me than AJAX+PHP... But I'm not giving up.

Today I found a great plugin that allows me to nicely upload files using jQuery AJAX and PHP ([Krajee Bootstrap FileInput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)), but I can't figure out what is causing this error:

Here's the HTML code:

```
<input id="escanneo" type="file" name="ticket[]" accept="image/*">
<div id="errorBlock43" class="help-block"></div>
```

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#escanneo").fileinput({
    //showPreview: false,
    browseClass: "btn btn-danger btn-block",
    showCaption: false,
    showRemove: false,
    showUpload: false,
    previewFileType: "image",
    browseLabel: " Subir ticket escanneado",
    browseIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>',
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "png", "PNG", "pdf"],
    elErrorContainer: "#errorBlock43",
    msgInvalidFileExtension: 'El formato de "{name}" es incorrecto. Solo archivos "{extensions}" son admitidos.',
    //AJAX
        dropZoneEnabled: false,
        uploadAsync: false,
        uploadUrl: "subir.php", // your upload server url
        uploadExtraData: function() {
            return {
                server: $("input[name='server']").val(),
                user: $("input[name='user']").val()
            };
        }
});
```

});

**upload.php file**:

```
<?php 
// upload.php de http://webtips.krajee.com/ajax-based-file-uploads-using-fileinput-plugin/
if (empty($_FILES['ticket'])) {
    return; // or process or throw an exception
}

// get the files posted
$ticket = $_FILES['ticket'];

// get server posted
$server = empty($_POST['server']) ? '' : $_POST['server'];

// get user name posted
$user = empty($_POST['user']) ? '' : $_POST['user'];

// a flag to see if everything is ok
$success = null;

// file paths to store
$paths= [];

// loop and process files
for($i=0; $i < count($ticket); $i++){
    $ext = explode('.', basename($ticket['name'][$i]));
    $target = "tickets/" . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);
    if(move_uploaded_file($ticket['tmp_name'][$i], $target)) {
        $success = true;
        $paths[] = $target;
    } else{
        $success = false;
        break;
    }
}

// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {
    // call the function to save all data to database
    // code for the following function `save_data` is not 
    // mentioned in this example
    save_data($userid, $username, $paths);

    // store a successful response (default at least an empty array). You
    // could return any additional response info you need to the plugin for
    // advanced implementations.
    $output = [];
} elseif ($success === false) {
    $output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading ticket. Contact the system administrator'];
    // delete any uploaded files
    foreach ($paths as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
} else {
    $output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}

// return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

and the file structure (subir.php = upload.php):

[image]

In case it's useful, here's my php error log:

```
[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(/tickets/cebcea25d53b5708b9e4612fd9871284.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php on line 26

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php:0

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. move_uploaded_file() C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php:26

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php195F.tmp' to '/tickets/cebcea25d53b5708b9e4612fd9871284.png' in C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php on line 26

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php:0

[21-Jan-2015 06:34:53 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. move_uploaded_file() C:\wamp\www\character-empower\subir.php:26
```

You can download and test a "lite" version I've made for this question here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5fBW4Q-fJQNHlGNXB6azNTRkE/view?usp=sharing

There should be some syntax error somewhere! Which I can't figure out...

Any hint/help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your directory for upload needs to be readable/writable and should exist. It seems you are using this on windows and folder separators are important.

Instead of forward slashes in your code use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in php (so it works both on windows or unix/linux web server platforms):

```
$target = "tickets" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);
```

Its been updated [in the webtip](http://webtips.krajee.com/ajax-based-file-uploads-using-fileinput-plugin/). BTW best of luck on [using my plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move the files to the `/tickets/` folder inside the server. Because the folder starts with `/` it is a absolute path.

If you want to upload the files to a `tickets/` folder at the same place of your `upload.php` replace:

```
$target = "/tickets/" . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);
```

with

```
$target = "tickets/" . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);
```

Now it will look for the relative path using the folder where `upload.php` is located as a base folder.

Comment: What change in the logs when you tried that? you can try to use: `$target = dirname(__FILENAME__) . "/tickets/" . md5(uniqid()) . "." . array_pop($ext);`. This will get the folder where the `upload.php` is located and prefix the `tickets` path.

Comment: Ok, I tried both of your examples, this is the error log for all of them: http://jpst.it/w4Np

Answer (score 0):

i think you have problems on defined Arrays, and also on upload function 
i modify your code to simplify it  and also test it its pretty work

Jquery Code :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

     var $input =   $('#escanneo');

          $input.fileinput({

    language: 'ar',
    browseClass: "btn btn-danger btn-block",
    showCaption: false,
    uploadAsync: false,
    showUpload: false, // hide upload button
    showRemove: false, // hid
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 8,
    previewFileType: "image",
    browseIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>',
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "png", "PNG", "pdf"],
         //AJAX
        dropZoneEnabled: false,
        uploadAsync: false,
        uploadUrl: "upper.php", // your upload server url
        uploadExtraData: function() {
            return {
                server: "server",
                user: "users"
            };
        }





    }).on("filebatchselected", function(event, files) {
    // trigger upload method immediately after files are selected
    $input.fileinput("upload");
});
```

and the PHP code :

```
<?php 
// upload.php de http://webtips.krajee.com/ajax-based-file-uploads-using-fileinput-plugin/
if (empty($_FILES['ticket'])) {
    return; // or process or throw an exception
}

// get the files posted


function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}




// get server posted
$server = empty($_POST['server']) ? '' : $_POST['server'];

// get user name posted
$user = empty($_POST['user']) ? '' : $_POST['user'];

// a flag to see if everything is ok
$success = null;

// file paths to store
$paths;


$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ticket']);

    foreach ($file_ary as $file) {



        $ext = explode('.',$file['name']);
    $target = "tickets/" . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[1];
    if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] , $target)) {
         $success = true;
     } else{
         $success = false;
         break;

    }


    }





// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {
    // call the function to save all data to database
    // code for the following function `save_data` is not 
    // mentioned in this example
 //   save_data($userid, $username, $paths);

    // store a successful response (default at least an empty array). You
    // could return any additional response info you need to the plugin for
    // advanced implementations.
   $output['done']= 'no problem';
} elseif ($success === false) {
    $output['error'] = 'Error while uploading ticket. Contact the system administrator';
    // delete any uploaded files
    foreach ($paths as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
} else {
    $output['error']= 'No files were processed.';
}

// return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

i don't think you still need it but its for other users might they will need it

best